# Compatibility between Browsers in ASPNET

Tags: html, text-editor

I'm using **HTML Editor** in my website. It is not visible in IE8 and Google Chrome. Any other Free html editor link is there which will support all the browsers?.

( Moreover, after clicking the HTML Editor, ajax is not working for me in that page. )

I need any other HTML Editor which will support all kind of browser especially Google Chrome

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is supported by most browsers. I've also used CKEditor in Chrome.

From [FCKeditor_3.x/Design_and_Architecture/Browsers_Compatibility](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_3.x/Design_and_Architecture/Browsers_Compatibility):

Officially, we'll be declaring support for the following browsers:

- Internet Explorer 6+
- Firefox 2+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9.5+

The editor can be downloaded from http://ckeditor.com/download . After you download the file you will find a "samples"-folder to get you started.

Comment: Sorry... I'm in out of time.. How to use it.. Can u show me the sample code for it

Comment: I've added a link to the download in my answer that includes the sample code.

Comment: Problem is when I'm clicking some other control in that web page, the HTML Editor is disabled. I can't able to access it. I used more than two html editor.. Each and everything shows that problem only.... I'm using ajax for other controls.

Comment: I found the Problem.. Problem is when I removed the ajax coding, it is working. If I use ajax, it is not working. This is the problem.. I dono wat is the solution for that